# Guzzle parameters multiple array

Tags: php, curl, guzzle

I have curl request:

```
curl http://example.com/json/get_products_by_multifilter -d '{"multifilter":{"limit":5}}'
```

My Guzzle code:

```
    $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();

    $request = $client->createRequest(
        'POST',
        'http://example.com/json/get_products_by_multifilter',
        array('multifilter' => array('limit' => 1))
    );
    $response = $client->send($request);

    echo $response->getBody();
```

I getting error:

**[InvalidArgumentException]

  No method can handle the multifilter config key**

What is wrong with my code, how to mase multiple array as a parameters ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Guzzle 5 you need to provide the post data inside the key **body**

Check the docs for more information: http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/clients.html

Example with **post** method:

```
$client->post('http://example.com/json/get_products_by_multifilter', [
    'body' => [
        'multifilter' => ['limit' => 1]
    ]
]);
```

With **createRequest**

```
$request = $client->createRequest(
    'POST',
    'http://example.com/json/get_products_by_multifilter',
    ['body' => 'multifilter' => ['limit' => 1]]
);
```

Every time you see the error

> [InvalidArgumentException] No method can handle the multifilter config
>   key

Means that the key you are using in **options** does not exist and guzzle does not know how to handle it.